# Select all input elements of a form the element belogs to

Tags: jquery, forms

I have multiple forms on a single MVC view. When a submit button on any of the forms is clicked, I need to get all the elements of type input belonging to that form and enable them.

This is what I tried but doesn't seem to be working.

```
$(this).parents('form:first').getElementsByTagName("input").prop("disabled", false);
$(this).parents('form:first').getElementsByTagName("input").removeClass("disabled");
```

Appreciate your help!!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This would be a correct syntax:

```
$(this).closest('form').find(":input").prop("disabled", false);
```

The [:input](https://api.jquery.com/input-selector/) is a jQuery extension that basically selects all form controls.

Answer (score 0):

I would go with

```
$(this).closest('form').find('input, select');
```

(in case you have select dropdowns as well.)

Comment: `form ` could contain button and textarea too. `:input` is better selector then: https://api.jquery.com/input-selector/

Comment: if all my buttons are some thing like this..  <button class="btn btn-ecp-blue" type="submit" id="btnUpdatePassword">Save</button>

Comment: add an onclick function to the button, and put one of our answers in that function.

Comment: $('selector').click(function(){$(this).closest('form').find('input, select').prop("disabled", false);});  ....what selector do I need to use?I dodnt want to use class selector

Comment: Thank you both for helping me! Both the answers have worked but I could mark only one as an answer. Since A. Wolff answered first I'll mark his as an answer.